# Converting Oracle timetamp type to Mysql timestamp type is wrong

Tags: mysql, oracle11g

My Oracle timestamp data is like `09-8月 -18 09.38.48.871000 上午`, and I want to insert it to Mysql from excel, But it is all  `0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000`, How should I do to converting it?

Comment: `09-8月 -18 09.38.48.871000 上午` looks chines.. Can you show the table structures for both DBMS (Oracle and MySQL)? I don't understand why excel is in this?

Comment: first, I export data from Oracle to excel, and then I want to import excel data to mysql, so it went wrang.the timetamp format of Oracle is `09-8月 -18 09.38.48.871000 上午`.@Raymond Nijland

Comment: "first, I export data from Oracle to excel, and then I want to import excel data to mysql" fair enough.. Can you show the table structures for both DBMS (Oracle and MySQL)?.. MySQL has a easy method `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` Oracle has dbms_metadata ( https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026 )

Comment: the mysql structure is `create table dmp(
    syscode varchar(10) NULL,
    insert_time timestamp(6) null)engine=InnoDB; `but I don't have the oracle structure, but I know the `INSERT_TIME` type is `timestamp`